# A Frustrating Set of Variables in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My industry (aftermarket auto components) utilizes a data standard for digital distribution, and I am currently attempting to create a living reference document, formatted with the correct information in the correct way, to make updating our standard database a less time consuming process.

My company has a 'Master Data Sheet' which contains every piece of data for all of the 20k+ products that we sell. All of our pricing and tracking sheets call cells or ranges from the Master Sheet, in addition to most of our front-facing web presence.

Here's my problem. The standard requires that our marketing descriptions be broken into separate lines with a specific identifier code and grouped by item ID:

```
Item ID          Desc Code          Desc
CHD001A          AAA                Brake Kit
CHD001A          BAA                Cross-drilled...
CHD001A          BAA                All of our...
CAE221B          AAA                Replacement Part
CAE221B          BAA                Reinforced with...
```

Our Master Data sheet has a different structure:

```
Item ID          Desc - AAA         Desc - BAA         Desc - BAA
CHD001A          Brake Kit          Cross drilled...   All of our...
CAE221B          Replacement Part   Reinforced with...
```

I'm completely stuck on how to get the right info into the right slots. I CANNOT alter the structure of the Master Sheet or I will have to remap at least thirty other spreadsheets. A VLOOKUP won't work in the horizontal way it needs to, and IF statements will get 20 nests in and then lack have a good way to group things. Please help.

Comment: _"I CANNOT alter the structure of the Master Sheet"_ So, do you want to generate a _new_ sheet with the "marketing structure" or what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can 1) Copy 2) Transpose Paste and 3) replace "Desc -  " with "" (nothing). If your goal is to automate this rather than do manually, you can write a couple of lines of code of VBA. Does this help? This could also be also be automated with one line of code with R or Python.

Comment: Since you have tagged your question with `VBA`, I'm guessing you want this to have a VBA solution. What code have you tried? This is a pretty straightforward data format change and doesn't really require use of copy-transpose-paste. Can you show what code you have?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your task is to find the description of item CH001A in the master db, and that you know the description code, you can use INDEX/MATCH. Here's the setup I used for developing the formula.

1. I created a simulation of your master in A1:D4 (one row more than the example in your question.
2. I assigned G2 as the cell where I would enter the Item ID and G3 to enter the Desc Code.
3. Now the formula `=IFERROR(MATCH(G2,A1:A4,0), 1)` finds the sheet row number by Item ID and `=IFERROR(MATCH("Desc - " & G3,A1:D1,0),1)` finds the sheet column number by Desc code. Note that both formulas default to 1 if not found.

Now the formula below will return the description.

```
=INDEX(A1:D4,IFERROR(MATCH(G2,A1:A4,0), 1),IFERROR(MATCH("Desc - " & G3,A1:D1,0),1))
```

Observe that the db range A1:D4 includes the captions and both range A1:A4 and A1:D1 start from the extreme top or left. This enables a column or row caption to be displayed in case of error (when an Item ID or Desc Code isn't found).

The formula isn't perfect yet but the method is. I take it that you will be able to tweak it to optimize adaptation to your needs. Let me know if you need help or advice with that.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple to do with `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+

- Select some cell in the `Master` Table

  - *If this is not a real **Table**, it will be changed into one*
- `Data` / `Get&Transform` / From `Table/Range`
- In the PQ editor window that opens, select the `Item Id` column

  - `Unpivot other columns`
- Split the resultant `Attribute` column by `Transition from non-digit to digit

  - *This will get rid of the automatically created suffixes caused by creating
    a table with initially identical column headers*
  - *If there are digits in the code itself, you'll need to remove the terminal digit(s) using a custom column with a formula.*

    - *The best way to do that would depend on the actual structure of your values*
- Delete the `Attribute.2` column (the one with the terminal digits)
- Rename the columns appropriately

[image]

Here is the generated M Code.

You can just paste this into the Advanced Editor of PQ.  If you do, be sure to change the Table Name in Line 2 to whatever your real table name for the Master Data turns out to be.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Master"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item ID", type text}, {"Desc - AAA", type text}, {"Desc - BAA", type text}, {"Desc - BAA2", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Item ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{"Attribute.2"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Attribute.1", "Desc Code"}, {"Value", "Desc"}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns", each ([Desc] <> ""))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```